# Embed async within a Monad implementing MonadIO

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I have some `pipes-concurrency` code that looks like this:

```
-- this won't compile but will give you the gist of what's happening
pipeline :: MonadIO m => Consumer a m ()
main = do
    (output, input) <- spawn Unbounded
    async $ do runEffect $ fromInput input >-> pipeline
               performGC
    -- skipped the `output` pipeline code.
```

**Question 1**: This obviously won't compile since `runEffect` will return `MonadIO m => m ()` and `async` requires `IO a`. Is there a way to do this? Or am I stuck forcing my pipeline to contain effects within the IO monad?

**Question 2**: does it even make sense to embed an async within a Monad implementing MonadIO? Not sure if I'm articulating myself well here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> This obviously won't compile since `runEffect` will return `MonadIO m => m ()` and async requires `IO a`

That's not quite right. `IO` *is* an instance of `MonadIO` so your output of `runEffect` could be passed to `async` or e.g. a function taking `MaybeT IO ()` (also a `MonadIO` instance).

I think what you're looking for is [`liftIO :: IO a -> m a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#v%3aliftIO), which will let you "lift" the specific `IO (Async a)` returned by `async` to a polymorphic `MonadIO` type as called for in your type signature.

```
...
liftIO $ async $ do runEffect $ fromInput input >-> pipeline
           performGC
```

Haven't tried to compile this; you may need to lift other `IO` parts of your functions as well.

> Question 2: does it even make sense to embed an async within a Monad implementing MonadIO? Not sure if I'm articulating myself well here.

Sure, if you want to do concurrency in some monad stack why not?

Comment: the problem is that `runEffect` will return `m ()` and `async` needs `IO a`.

Comment: @weirdcanada as I said that's not the problem. You can convince yourself with dummy implementations in GHCi. Enter the following lines: `data Effect m r = Effect (m r)`, `let runEffect :: Monad m => Effect m r -> m r ; runEffect = undefined`, `data Async a`, `let async :: IO a -> IO (Async a) ; async = undefined`, `:t async $ runEffect undefined`. You may have other issues, but it's difficult to help without a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Hmm... I think I'm missing something. I'll get a SSCCE soon (currently on the road on mobile). I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the exact same thing and this is the core of the problem:

```
$ :t async . runEffect
async . runEffect :: Effect IO a -> IO (Async a)
$
```

In a nutshell, I am expected to provide something of this type. But the type that I really want is:

```
someAsync . runEffect :: MonadIO m => Effect m a -> m (Async a)
```

Unfortunately I am not sure how to make this happen. Currently this seems impossible but not because of pipes-concurrency and purely because of the types of async.

I think we should point the developers of both libraries to this question because, otherwise, I don't see how to get the type that I want.

**Edit 1**: I have found this issue where they [do not want to add MonadIO support to async](https://github.com/simonmar/async/issues/16).

**Edit 2**: I love the Pipes library but I am having difficulty finding a solution to this problem. If I can't find the answer to this problem then [I might use buffer from Data.Conduit.Async](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-conduit-2.1.3/docs/Data-Conduit-Async.html) because it seems to solve this problem really nicely.

**Edit 3**: It seems that the right solution to this problem is to use [lifted-async](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-async). This library provides the following method:

```
async :: MonadBaseControl IO m => m a -> m (Async (StM m a))
```

That should do exactly what you are loking for so long as you implement MonadBaseControl IO for your Monad.